# Is it possible to develop a browser plugin which can redirect the users to a new url automatically when they try to visit some sites?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

Such as, with the plugin installed, when you visit [www.google.com](http://www.google.com), then you will be redircted to [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com)
I want to develop a chrome/firefox plugins for this, but I don't know whether it is possible.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Your use case sounds extremely malicious.

Comment: Thariq,,,,,,,you are right. It can be malicious, but I won't do any harm to the user, or to anybody I promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible, you first need to get currently active tab's id, then you can open another location in this tab, demo:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, function(tabArray) {                      
        var currentURL = tabArray[0].url;
        if(currentURL == "https://www.google.com/"){
            chrome.tabs.update(tabArray[0].id, {url: yournewurl});
        }
});
```

If you want to automatically check whether currenturl is google, then you will need to put this code into background.html, and force background to alaways check active url, when tabs were updated, so to fire the upper code, you should use `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(redirect);` where redirect could be a function in background.html containing the code upper. Jim

Answer (score 0):

Well, an easier way is to use the [webRequest API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/webRequest.html):

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) { return {url: "http://www.mysite.com"}; },
  {urls: ["*://www.google.com/*"],
  ["blocking"]
);
```